# How to pass multiple values to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, stored-procedures

I have an Excel worksheet with a dropdown data validation box where the user can select from a list of integer values to determine a department or the word "ALL" to get all departments.  I'm passing that cell's value to a stored procedure using SQL. In the SQL, I have `WHERE Department=@Dept`.

If I'm only going to allow one department choice, this works fine, but I want to also allow for all departments.

Are there any ideas on how to make that work?  Does it take some sort of trick with the `IN` operator or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement, so if it's "ALL" you can pass back the Department field. If it's anything else pass the value you sent in:

```
Where Department = CASE @input WHEN 'ALL' Then Department ELSE @input END
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The syntax which ultimately helped was as follows:  WHERE Department=case when @Dept='ALL' then Department else @Dept end

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions here in the stored script:

1. put an `if` statement then you'll have to sets of queries.
2. put an `iif`/`case` statement within the criteria.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I decided to use method 2 which was of great help!  Your answer in combination with the others was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If your user selects "ALL", you can set the paramter to NULL:

```
select * from table1 WHERE Department=isnull(@Dept,Department)
```

When the value of `@Dept` is NULL the query will be:

```
select * from table1 WHERE Department=Department
```

just like `1=1`.

Comment: Thank you.  So how would you set the parameter to NULL.  What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Your answer in combination with the others helped me solve this issue.